# Google navigation stuck on "Checking navigation availability"

Tags: google-maps, navigation, google-maps-navigation

I own a LG Optimus One with Android 2.2.2. Everytime I try to use the navigation provided by google, my phone remains stuck on `Checking navigation availability`. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Is your GPS turned on?

Comment: Wifi probably needs to be on, too.

Comment: You might try clearing the app data and/or cache and see if that helps.

Comment: Both GPS and Wifi were on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was running the 5.0 version of google maps. I tried to search for an update on the market, but I couldn't even find the app. The most surprising thing was that using the exact search strings, I was able to find it very easy in the browser.

I downloaded the 5.2 apk, and I installed it from the SDCard. Afterwards, everything worked.